# Run Ant tast from Jenkins on Perforce

Tags: ant, jenkins, perforce

I'm trying to integrate Jenkins with Perforce, but I'm having a few problems.
I managed (apparently, because Jenkins still shows a "Unable to check workspace against depot" message) to link Jenkins to Perforce.

My project includes an Ant script to make the build and I cannot figure out how to use it.
I've added an Ant build step, indicating the name of the ant file (dev_build.xml), but when I run the job Jenkins complains that it cannot find the Ant file.
Jenkins looks for the file in its workspace, but the file is actually located in Perforce's workspace. I expected Jenkins to check out the project but this is not happening: the folder Jenkins\Workspace\MyProject is empty.

I've then copied the Ant file into Jenkins workspace folder, but obviously the Ant fails because it cannot find the source folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Jenkins should sync all required files to the workspace. But that doesn't seem to work because of the "Unable to check workspace against depot" message. You should check the jobs' perforce setup.

Comment: How do I check? In the job's console I can see it connect to Perforce.

Comment: One way would be to add a "shell build task" and run "p4 have" to see if perforce thinks that you have all the files that it should have. Then check the console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a new perforce workspace dedicated to Jenkins, mapped to the workspace folder.
P4 now synchronizes the files correctly.